# How to access data from cassandra installed on CENTOS server from windows?

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

my casssndra is installed in CENTOS server and i want to access the data of that data base from my own system . i've witten web service for that but i dont know how to connect it from my windows system . any body knows how to do that ??

```
public class Dbconnection {


    public static Session connector(String CASSANDRA_HOST , int CASSANDRA_PORT ,String CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE){
    static Cluster cluster;
    static Session session; 
        try {
                cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(CASSANDRA_HOST).withPort(CASSANDRA_PORT).build();
                session = cluster.connect(CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE);
            }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("INVALID CONNECTION STRING");
            }

        if(session!=null)
            System.out.println("Connection Opened Successfully at "+CASSANDRA_HOST+":"+CASSANDRA_PORT+" With Workspace "+CASSANDRA_KEYSPACE);

        return session;
    }public static void main(String[] args) 
    Session session=Dbconnection.connector("192.168.30.17" ,9042,'temperature');}
```

instead of "197.168.30.17" when i put localhost it gets connected to locally installed cassandra .
but it not getting connected to cassndrawhich i've installed on Centos server .(IP:192.168.30.17)

Comment: What needs to connect to what? Your web service to cassandra?, Directly to cassandra? Your client to the web service? What type of Web Service, How are you connecting?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you can reach the server running cassandra from your system?
Also check if the firewall in the machine running cassandra is allowing traffic for that port?